# How to use AppNexus service via appnexusapi gem

Tags: ruby

I am using `appnexusapi` gem to connect with AppNexus api but I am not able to proceed beyond establishing a basic connection.

Here is my ruby code:

```
require 'appnexusapi'

conn = AppnexusApi::Connection.new({'uri' => 'http://api.appnexus.com/auth', 'username' =>'*****','password' => '******'})

key = conn.login
```

As the documentation is not good, I am unable to proceed further. I would like to generate reports and query the data service.

In appnexus console I found that it generates random id for every report.

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Priti, as the documentation is not good I am unable to proceed but in appnexus console I found that it generates random id for every report.

Comment: @pramod: Welcome to SO. Hope you don't mind I edited your question, including information from your comment, to try and help things along

Answer (score 2):

To generate a report, you need to POST to the /report service with the proper json for the report you want.  The easiest way to generate this json is to manually create a sample report in Console and then hit Ctrl+J to see the json used.  You can then alter as necessary for your exact needs.

Once you have the json, make a POST to the /report service and you'll receive a unique report_id (for that specific report request).  Using this report_id, make a GET call to the /report?id= service and look for the 'execution_status' field.  When that field is 'ready', you can grab the 'url' field to get the path to actually download the data (something like /report-download?id=13828374).  Make a GET to that url and you'll have all of your data.

Details are available on the AppNexus wiki if you are a client: https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/api/Report+Service